Induced homology map zero implies zero in cobordism?
I had asked this in math stackexchange, but got no reply. Hence, I'm asking here.
[I'm no expert in (co)bordism theory, and I've been struggling with it for the past few weeks. Any good references on this direction would be very helpful as well.]
Suppose $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is a (continuous or appropriate) map of spaces. We know that it induces a map $f_*$ on homology.
It also induces a map $F$ on the (oriented) (co)bordism group $\Omega_n^{SO}(X) \rightarrow \Omega_n^{SO}(Y)$.
If $f$ induces a zero map on homology (in degrees $\geq 1$), what can we say about the (oriented) (co)bordism map $F$? Is it zero as well (in degrees $\geq 1$) ?
In particular, if $X$ and $Y$ are classifying spaces of infinite (discrete) groups (classifying space by the nerve construction), can we say that the (oriented) bordism map is zero as well?
That is, for two infinite discrete groups $G$ and $H$, suppose $f : G \rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism and induce zero map on homology groups (of the classifying spaces) in degrees $\geq 1$.
Then, is the induced map $\Omega_n^{SO}(BG) \rightarrow \Omega_n^{SO}(BH)$ zero (in degrees $\geq 1$)?

The representing spectrum $MSO$ of oriented bordism splits $2$-locally as a wedge of suspensions of the representing spectra $H\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$ and $H\mathbb{F}_2$ for $2$-local homology and mod $2$ homology, respectively. So if a map of spaces or spectra induces the zero map in $2$-local homology and mod $2$ homology, then that map induces the zero map in $2$-local oriented bordism. Is this what you are looking for, or are you after odd-primary answers too?

Sorry for the late reply. I think I'm looking for something else (to be honest, I haven't understood what you have said, as I'm not very familiar with it though - sorry!). Do you know of any good references?
